# Creating a dictionary from a text file and include a translation

Tags: python, dictionary, translation

I need to create a dictionary for an app by importing words from a txt file. Once this has been done, it is necessary that the user, when typing a word in one of the two languages, receives the correct translation.

Here what I wrote:

```
def get_pair(line):
    key, sep, value = line.strip().partition(",")
    return key, value
filename = "words.txt"
with open(filename,encoding= 'utf-8') as fd:
    d = dict(get_pair(line) for line in fd)

def translate (words):
    translation = ""
    for word in d:
        if word in d(0):
            translation = d(-1)
        if word in d(-1) :
            translation = d(0)
            return translation
print(translate(input("Enter a word")))
```

I don't receive the translation! Someone can help?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"It doesn't work" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code.

```
def translate (words):
    translation = ""
    for word in d:
        if word in d[0]:
            translation = d[-1]
        if word in d[-1] :
            translation = d[0]
            return translation
print(translate(input("Enter a word")))
```

This now should work. You can't index a tuple with `()`, but rather with `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to look the work "words" in your dictionary and retrun the translation. Here is how you can do it:

```
def translate (words):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if words == key:
            return value
        if words value :
            return key
print(translate(input("Enter a word")))
```